# Diaspora (Ruby) run Error, Maybe PATH Problem? "uninitialized constant TurboDevAssets (NameError)"

Tags: ruby, gentoo, diaspora

I try to migrate diaspora from a damaged debian 8 to another gentoo. I want to be able to can run diaspora before I deploy the web server. I crashes because of Ruby Errors, maybe kind of `PATH` errors.

When I run diaspora with `script/server` in production mode it crashes because the thing behind web.pid crashes. In the log `eye_processes_stderr.log` is:

```
bin/bundle:3:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/bin/bundle (LoadError) 
        from bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

In development mode I can not execute correctly (I tried it to get better error message reporting):

```
RAILS_ENV=development bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
bin/rake assets:precompile
```

because of the stdout and stderr of `script/server` I run: `bin/bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb`

In production mode it returns:
that I shall look into stderr 
and in the log there is nothing helpful, in:
`tail log/eye_processes_stderr.log`:

```
bin/bundle:3:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/bin/bundle (LoadError)
         from bin/bundle:3:in `<main>' bin/bundle:3:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/bin/bundle (LoadError)
         from bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

But in development mode it returns:

```
I, [2019-10-07T11:14:20.840060 #20262]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/config/environments/development.rb:64:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant TurboDevAssets (NameError)
         from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:211:in `instance_eval'
         from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:211:in `configure'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/config/environments/development.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from config.ru:10:in `require'
        from config.ru:10:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:54:in `eval'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:54:in `block in builder'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:794:in `build_app!'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:141:in `start'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/bin/unicorn:128:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

and now it returns that also in production mode, after I executed it in development mode.

line 64 in 
`/home/diaspora/diaspora-2017-07-07-newest/config/environments/development.rb`
 is:

```
  # Speed up asset serving
  config.middleware.insert 0, TurboDevAssets
```

It shall run as it did with every working diaspora as it has worked on debian 8 when I used rvm in the home directory. (as I also tried that on the Gentoo machine)

Comment: thats a pain to read. Please use code formatting blocks for your error messages so that user can separate your text form the program output stuff.

Comment: To be honest you probably just got confused. The only way I can imagine it loading `development.rb` with  `RAILS_ENV=production`  is when spring is running and while the backtrace does not indicate it does, ensure so by running `bin/spring stop` or even rebooting the box. Also that you went from a missing or borked bundler install to this error just by switching `RAILS_ENV` is more than unlikely, you probably did things not described here in between. Make sure to run in production mode again if this is aimed as a production install and describe your current state and setup better :)

Comment: I explained what happens, if I execute it in production mode. It just prints out, that I shall read stderr. And the log file regarding stderr just says, that it can not load that what I said so above. I executed it later in development mode, because the output at production mode was not helpful for me. I am gonna try now what u propose!

Comment: bin/spring stop tells me:  Could not find 'spring'. Why havent it had installed spring from their Gemfile? I am a Ruby Deployment newbie.

Comment: It did not install spring, because it belongs to the development group in der Gemfile, but what I want is production mode.